# HashTable Folding method

Tags: java, hash

I'm trying to write a shift folding method for HashTable.

The method passes a key(int) value, and the key value is broken into groups of digits and the groups are added. The number of digits in a group should correspond to the arraySize.

**EX) Input arraySize = 15; key = 123;**

**Output : 12+3 = 15**

However the method I wrote does it backward.

```
public class C{
public int folding(int key)
{
  int digit =1; // how many digits in arraySize?
  int arraySize =15; //if 15, 2-digits
  int hashVal =0; 

  while(arraySize >0 ){ //digit is 100;
      digit *= 10;
      arraySize /= 10;
  }

  while(key>0){  //hashVal should be 15
      hashVal +=key%digit;
      key /= digit;
  }
  System.out.print(hashVal);
  return hashVal;


}


public static void main(String[] args) {
C g = new C();
g.folding(123);
}
}
```

I get

**1+23 = 24**

Can some modifications to my original code fix it to give the expected output?

Or is the only way to do this to convert the arraySize(int) to String and parse the keyValue by its length?

Comment: You can, though to implement your first suggestion is slower and more complex.  Note: either solution can produce a number >= 100, so you have to mod the sum as well.

Comment: yes I was going to add it after I figure out how to correctly implement the steps before. Thank you for the reminder tho! I still haven't figured out how to implement first or second :'(

Comment: Are you sure you have to implement the hashing this way?  If you used a power of 2 for example, this would not only be much more efficient but simpler.

Comment: Yes, I'm kinda getting the sense that this might not be the best way for all the trouble I'm going through :(. But I'm just doing it for practice.

Comment: I agree, I suggest you try a hashing strategy which is more efficient, and covers things like negatives.  Hint: `%` and `/` are not very efficient, `>>` and `^` and `&` more more efficient. http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2015/08/comparing-hashing-strategies.html